# Webgl Framebuffer low Picture - Quality

Tags: android, image, webgl, framebuffer

My framebuffer has very low picture- quality (Android). What can I do to get better quality? Hier is a screen shot:

[image]

Hier is a part of my code:

```
RenderingEngine.prototype.getPixel = function(x, y, drawObjects){
var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
framebuffer.width = this.canvas.width;
framebuffer.height = this.canvas.height;

var depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

// allocate renderbuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach renderebuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

var colorBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
// allocate colorBuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach colorbuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   alert("this combination of attachments does not work");
}

gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); 
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

renderingEngine.draw(drawObjects);
var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, this.canvas.height - y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
return pixel;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe most mobile browsers default to a 16bit canvas as it's significantly faster so the following may not work but ...

Instead of making a `gl.RGBA4` Renderbuffer make a `gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture

Change this

```
var colorBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
// allocate colorBuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach colorbuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
```

To this

```
var colorTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture);
// allocate colorTexture
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 
              framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height, 0,
              gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// make it work even if not a power of 2
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// attach colortexture
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);
```

Comment: Yes I get high quality Picture now. Thank you very much!